# Creating Databases/Users Through Code/Command server with WHM/Cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, database, shell, cpanel

I am trying to write a PHP/Shell command that creates a database on a WHM/cPanel server. Here is what I have tried:
 - Accessed SSH through Putty
 - Connected to mysql server using `mysql -p`
 - Ran the command `create database cpaneluser_newdatabase;`

However, I get the following error:

> Access denied for user 'cpanel_username'@'localhost' to database
>   'cpaneluser_newdatabase'

I need a way to create a database, a user, and assign a database privileges to that user. Pretty much the exact same process we do through the cPanel interface, but through code/command.

Note that I have root/WHM access.

Comment: You must to me edited your question adding Cpanel. It's important. Some answers are dangerous for your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Access denied for user 'cpanel_username'@'localhost' to database 'cpaneluser_newdatabase'
```

means  User: cpanel_username , accessed at localhost ,has no privileges to access database cpaneluser_newdatabase;

try to login the mysql with root, and grant privileges to ;

use `grant all on cpaneluser_newdatabase.* to cpanel_username@'localhost'`

PS:

cpanel_username@'localhost' is very strange....

better use the mysqlclient like this:

```
mysql -u<username> -p
```

Comment: Granting privileges did it! Thanks

Comment: @DanielR. If used well, the user will not see the database in your cpanel. Cpanel will not make backups of the database. You should use API calls WHM-. Follow that answer is the best path to a disaster in Cpanel.https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/Guide+to+WHM+API+1 and https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/cPanel+API+2+Functions+-+MysqlFE%3A%3Acreatedb

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a password for that mysql user which is supposed to access the cPanel mysql database:

```
CREATE DATABSE cpaneluser_newdatabase;
CREATE USER 'cpaneluser_mysqluser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-password';
GRANT ALL ON cpaneluser_newdatabase.* to cpaneluser_mysqluser@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score -1):

Bottom-line: you need to adjust the remote MySQL settings on the cPanel/host side before you will be allowed to perform operations like this remotely.

This really depends on your cpanel/web hosting provider, though. Permissions for these kinds of things are specific to each but are generally more restrictive by default.

The general idea is that you're going to need to create a new database user specific to your application that can grant permissions to new users that are created within your application. You do not want to use your cpanel credentials within your app -- if it gets hacked then they have instant access to absolutely everything on your server, rather than just one part of it (your app).

1. Chances are that if you are logging into mysql from a different IP
   address/machine than where cpanel/mysql is hosted that you do not have
   permissions to login remotely yet. That's going to be your first
   step to set up:
   http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/enable-remote-mysql-connections-in-cpanel/
2. Once you have remote mysql set up for your IP and user, you should be able to connect to mysql through ssh as you did previously and create a new user  and database for your application.
3. Now that you have a new user, use that NEW application-specific user to manage your new database and assign privileges to other users who should have access to it. Only provide database privileges to users who need them and remember to always be only assign privileges that are actually needed. If you're not sure if they will need something, then don't assign it until a case comes up where they actually do.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I don't think my question or situation has anything to do with "remote access."

Comment: The answer has nothing to do with the question.